# How do I attach 2 buttons to 2 piston doors?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want to put 2 buttons on 2 piston hidden door and i can't succeed. It works only with one buttons. How can i create a circuit to open the door from all parts.
I attach photo to see more easy what i do to construct.
[image: 1]
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is by running a second redstone line from below the dirt block to the redstone torch. (Dirt replaced with glass for transparency).

[image: Door with redstone line from under dirt to below redstone torch]

You can also extend the existing redstone to below the dirt block, and replace the block below the redstone torch with a target block to redirect the redstone dust into the block.

[image: Door with block below redstone torch replaced with target block]

Comment: Thanks! It works with the second one. Thanks a lot!